# Uncaught exception raised in open directory client-side plugin

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, open-directory, serveradmin

When I attempt to change the open directory settings for 10.6 server using ServerAdmin I get the following error.

This prevents me from making any changes to any open directory settings for the system.

Does anybody have any ideas on how to solve the issue?

[image: Example error message]

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific as to what you are trying to change in your OD? Is the OD a master or replica? When did the issue start occuring? Maybe restart the server temporarily in save mode and see if the plug-in error remains.

Comment: It doesn't appear to matter what I change.  Any of the OpenDirectory settings appear to trigger this issue, but I first became aware of it specifically when I was attempting to change the LDAP SSL certificate.  The OD server is a master with no replication server configured.

Answer (score 1):

It seems difficult to believe that it is as you suspect, that something that a client did has locked you out of control of [your own server](http://manuals.info.apple.com/MANUALS/1000/MA1180/en_US/OpenDirAdmin_v10.6.pdf).

Check permissions! Break out the Terminal and attempt to discover where the [critical configuration files are](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH8387) for Open Directory, and make sure your permissions ( `ls -l` ) haven't been "bonked" <-- (sorry for the inscrutable admin rhetioric ;-)

Also, if you find the config file(s) in question, you will be able to examine and edit manually ( `sudo cat ____` and `sudo vi ____`). If these files are in an xml binary form, they can be converted with `plutil -convert xml1 config.plist` and converted back with `pluitil -convert binary1 config.plist` -- as always, copy the orginals somewhere else, back them up, and work with copies to experiment, so you can always restore them necessary.

---

also you can attempt to use the [`serveradmin`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/8/serveradmin/) (<---that's hotlinked) command line tool to attempt what the GUI is preventing you from doing. [here](http://manuals.info.apple.com/MANUALS/1000/MA1173/en_US/IntroCommandLine_v10.6.pdf) is another good reasource, as well as [here](http://manuals.info.apple.com/MANUALS/0/MA519/en_US/MacOSXSrvr10.3_CommandLineAdminGuide.pdf)

---

It is difficult to diagnose/troubleshoot this without having access to the machine, so I hope I give you ideas to try that may lead to new paths to a solution. Again, let me know in comments if this answer is not helpful, and I will again delete to prevent noise. Good luck!